# Starting From Scratch - What SQL database should I use with Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, windows, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I recently got a new primary computer.  On my old one, I was working with MS Visual Studio 2008 (or maybe an older version - I can't remember now).  I had managed to get SQLite working with it and was in the start/middle of building an application.

On the new computer, I now have MS Visual Studio 2010.  I have had problems getting SQLite to work with it.  Honestly, I haven't tried super hard yet, because I realized I pretty much want to completely redesign this application anyway and it got me thinking... do I really want to use SQLite or some other SQL?  MS SQL (or is it called SQL Server)?  MySQL?

My end goal is to have an application that can be installed by the user with one .msi file and the user should not have direct access to the database (although at this stage, that is a secondary concern).

It seems like MS SQL / SQL Server is the easiest since it's also an MS product....  Would love some opinions!

(along with the opinions, I'd also love to be pointed to current instructions... I'm a programmer, I'm not a "coding environment setup" person and have always struggled with this.  All I want is to get in there and write my application!)

Thanks in advance!

-Adeena

PS... I'm currently working with C# and would prefer to stick with it, but could easily do this in C++ (I'm fluent in all the flavors of C) if that makes a difference with the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server would be a good choice by the sounds of what you're after. Try the express version - it's free, good for development and prototyping and integrates really well with Visual Studio.

The SQL Server Management Studio tool is excellent. I use this to create the databases I need and then use Visual Studio to manage them (saves switching windows and running both applications when you're working in VS all day anyway). I used to have my issues with the old Enterprise manager software but things really seems to have stepped up for SQL Server 2008 and the new management studio.

Like the title of your question suggests, you're wanting to use this with Visual Studio. If you decide to do use SQL Server then you should:

Download the express edition

Download SQL Server management studio

Create a database

In Visual Studio - click View -> Server explorer -> right click Data connections and add connection. Select MS SQL Express and choose localhost as your server. You can then select the database you created using the management studio.

There you have it - integration with VS.

You say you're using C#.Net - well SQL server and .Net go hand-in-hand. Obviously you can hook up to other third party databases but SQL was really made to work with this stuff. It's a powerful database engine and will do everything you'll ever need as well as being well supported by Microsoft and the wider community.

Comment: Thanks!  This sounds like it is probably what I want to work with right now.   (How long has then been out?  I'm wondering how I went down the path of SQLite in the first place...)

Comment: All the tools I've mentioned have been around since the release of SQL server 2008 - good luck with it all :)

Comment: Any hints on installing it with Windows 7??  I'm getting the "compatibility" message as expected, but then running into another error.  Of course, I didn't install PowerShell, but that's because the website doesn't say anythign about Windows 7 on it...

Answer (score 2):

If your final goal is to have hands-off single-click installation then I don't think SQL Server Express is your best bet because it's not a file-based embedded database. It's a great db and very easy to work with, but when it comes to deployment still takes some installation effort. You could try one of: SQL Server Compact Edition, SQLite or Firebird Embedded.

Comment: What is the difference between SQL Server Express and SQL Server Compact Edition?  Are they both MS products?  Any reason not to get started with SQL Server Express and evolve later?  My first priority is an easy install.  Second priority is a database that can be protected in some way from the user manually editting it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLExpress is free and for development purposes is pretty much interchangeable with the full SQLServer

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER seems to be the logical one.